# Where can I find a 2x2 hinge on Bricklink?

Tags: star-wars, part-identification, bricklink

In this picture "[The neglect of duty](https://www.flickr.com/photos/storm_tk431/6599195483/in/album-72157626229447802/)" by Je hyung Lee, he uses four 2x2 hinges in the roof section I can't find on Bricklink.

[image: The neglect of duty]

Does anybody have an idea what set this comes out and possibly a Bricklink link to it or another similar site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a LEGO part. It's closest LEGO cousin would be [3149](http://rebrickable.com/parts/3149c01/hinge-plate-2-x-5-%5Bcomplete-assembly%5D):

[image: 3149c01]

3149-like hinges don't have a 2x2 version to the best of my knowledge. In addition, the part in the picture appears to be 12 ldu (1.5 plates) thick. This leads me to believe that it is actually a Tyco part.

Also, it looks like this has already been [discussed on Eurobricks](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=93665) where the same conclusion was drawn. From that thread:

[image: pic pointing out Tyco brick]

Comment: I can confirm that the hinge is a Tyco brand brick.  I got a large set of these as a kid and still have them.  The Tyco plates are half brick height, which can come in handy sometimes when building SNOT elements if you are not a LEGO purist.

Comment: Thank you. This was driving me nuts. And thanks for the link to the other Eurobricks forum.  When I look at it I see the big difference in plate size also

@Josh King thanks for the confirmation